# Convert South African time to universal time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I want to convert South African time to any universal time. I have the following values available: timezone (i.e. 60 for Brussels) and offset = 60.

I've tried this:

```
var newDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
```

But it doesn't give me the correct date time value for Brussels.

Comment: You should play (read learn) with culture and timezones.

Comment: In what way is "60" the time zone for Brussels?

Comment: You should use `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("South Africa Standard Time");` in the answer given by `@Marco` . Where you will get Standard Time Zone: `UTC/GMT +2 hours`

Comment: Hi Jon, the "60" value represent minutes which equals Brussels' current time zone offset: UTC/GMT +2 hours. Will edit my question for clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert any `DateTime` to universal time (UTC) using [DateTime.ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since Brussells is one hour ahead, add one hour to that (if they are in daylight savings) or two hours otherwise.

Comment: I tried this as you advised and it works great. 

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime);
    dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-120);
    if (city.TimeZone != null)
    {
        dateTime = dateTime.AddMinutes(city.TimeZone.Value);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx) you could use something like this (remember to choose correct time zone):

```
DateTime hwTime = DateTime.Now;
try
{
   TimeZoneInfo hwZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time");
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} is {2} local time.", 
           hwTime, 
           hwZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(hwTime) ? hwZone.DaylightName : hwZone.StandardName, 
           TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(hwTime, hwZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local));
}
catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The registry does not define the Hawaiian Standard Time zone.");
}                           
catch (InvalidTimeZoneException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Registry data on the Hawaiian STandard Time zone has been corrupted.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx